# Reading Binary Data Using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binaryfiles

I am trying to read files containing gridded data that are formatted as flat binary 16-bit signed integer big-endian. I am using `struct.unpack()`, which I believe is correct as it allows me to specify the data is both signed and big-endian, but I am not sure of it recognizes the data as 16-bit. If possible, can someone confirm this is the correct method for reading the type of data I have described.

```
>>>file_name = 'some_file.dat'
>>>file = open(file_name, 'rb')
>>>data = struct.unpact('>h', file.read())
>>>print(data)
(-9999,)
```

I would like to read the entire file at once, and insert the data into a numpy array. I know the dimensions of the array and the direction used to populate the array from these files.

Thank you for any and all assistance.

Comment: `while` and `with` do completely different things.  `with` isn't even a looping construct.  Trying to compare the "performance differences" between these things is like asking if carrots taste like blue.

Comment: How many values are in a "real" file?  Does the file contain *only* 16 bit integers (i.e. no header, no other data)?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The file contains only 16bit integers, the header is provided in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `numpy` tag on the question, so I assume a numpy solution is acceptable.  You can read the data using numpy's [`fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) function.  `fromfile` allows you to specify the data type, including endianness.  For example,

```
In [1]: !hexdump x16.dat
0000000 00 01 01 01 ff ff 04 00 04 01 ff e8 00 00 00 f0
0000010

In [2]: x = np.fromfile('x16.dat', dtype='>i2')

In [3]: x
Out[3]: array([   1,  257,   -1, 1024, 1025,  -24,    0,  240], dtype=int16)
```

Answer (score 1):

16 bit signed integers [are h; b is 8-bit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). So you want `struct.unpack('>h', file.read())`.